# PHP Query into CURL

Tags: php, curl

i have a simple function, which should query the USGN number from the table and insert it into CURL request, but its giving white page...

For my bad luck i cannot provide error, its just blank page.

here is the script:

```
function getUSGNavatar($id) {
$usgn = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cm_users WHERE USGN = '$usgn' AND ID = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
return mysql_fetch_assoc($usgn);

// CURL 
$ch = curl_init('http://www.unrealsoftware.de/getuserdata.php?id='$usgn'&data=avatar');
curl_exec($ch);
if(!curl_errno($ch))
{
 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
// CLOSE function
}
```

Thanks for help

Something messed up with the query part i am sure, curl works okay, when ididn't used mysql worked fine.

I will rewrite Mysql into PDO, or MySQLI please dont mention it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: See link @CharlotteDunois posted, and turn on error reporting please.

Comment: Its turned on, but its defined in my functions.php, where there is thousand other function :/

Comment: However i turned on, but still no errors just blank page

Comment: I made a new file with the function and now what i can see if undefine $usgn = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cm_users WHERE USGN = '$usgn' AND ID = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
 return mysql_fetch_assoc($usgn); this part and remove id's and $usgn from curl thing its works fine, but i need to get that USGN number by mysql :(

Comment: You should be getting a syntax error for the `$ch =` line, because you're missing the `.` to concatenate the strings with the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning i.e. `return mysql_fetch_assoc($usgn);`
 and you should not be as this will finish the function at that point.

Oh and your string building in 
`$ch = curl_init('http://www.unrealsoftware.de/getuserdata.php?id='$usgn'&data=avatar');` also had a problem.

```
function getUSGNavatar($id) {
    $usgn = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                         FROM cm_users 
                         WHERE ID = '$id'");
    if ( ! $usgn ) {
        echo mysql_error();
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($usgn);

    // CURL 
    $ch = curl_init('http://www.unrealsoftware.de/getuserdata.php?id=' . 
                    $row['USGN'] . '&data=avatar');
    curl_exec($ch);
    if(!curl_errno($ch)) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    // now you probably want to return something from the function
    return $info;
}
```

> Oh and as per your request I will not nag you about the use of the deprecated `mysql_` database extension, because we believe you that you will rewrite this code once its working, dont we?

Comment: exactly, now i dont get error, but i dont get my avatar so there is no url returned

Comment: When I run `www.unrealsoftware.de/getuserdata.php?id=1&data=avatar` I get `u_ava/u1_4e989c1e.jpg` returned. Are you sure you are using this returned information correctly. Then when I look at the url `http://www.unrealsoftware.de/u_ava/u1_4e989c1e.jpg` I see an image

Comment: http://www.unrealsoftware.de/getuserdata.php?id=6943&data=avatar

i should get back this filename back and i can insert it into <img src="http://unrealsoftware.de/"functionname($id)"> 

But right now i got nothing :S

Comment: however i just tried to echo it, its still not display the filename

Comment: Try `echo getUSGNavatar(6943);` what does that return

Comment: Returns Array thats all

Comment: So do `print_r(getUSGNavatar(6943));` and see what the function is returning and amend what it returns accordingly so your `<img...` gets what it wants

Comment: This is rapidly getting into the area of Question.Scope Creep. I think you need to finish with this question as it is answered and ask a new question. Oh and delete that answer, thats not how you add info to a question. In future edit your question.

Comment: Ask a new question? Sorry but i dont know what could i say for the "problem".

Comment: I get this data and I dont know what to do with it

Comment: Maybe you should also check what is returned from the query as that data shows nothing in the `id=` field on the url. I dont know what the columns are actually called on your database so `$row['USGN']` may be misspelled

Comment: Actually I just spotted a **possible** mistake in your QUERY. I removed `USGN = '$usgn'` from your WHERE as I see no `$usgn` for you to use in this scope

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8bxf01

its looks like this, however i deleted USGN = '$usgn' but still not work

Comment: You need to do some research on the extra CURL parameters you need to get curl to run properly

Comment: Problem with no CURL i fugred out

Now i trying to run

function getUSGNavatar($id) {
    $usgn = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cm_users WHERE ID = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($usgn);
    
 echo "sad " . $row['USGN']. " when";
}

and just return "sad when" without ID, so problem with query

Comment: $usgn = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cm_servers WHERE ID = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($usgn);
 echo mysql_error();

like this? i did but no errors

Comment: Fixed the issue by my self! However you answered the most helpful answer so take my like!

Answer (score 1):

you're getting the blank page because of this:

```
id='$usgn'&data
```

change this to:

```
id='.$usgn.'&data
```

you're missing the "."

Comment: That will fix the syntax error, but not make the function work correctly.